# Observable<T> returning type T after calling method subscribe()

Tags: functional-programming, rx-java

I'm dealing with Observables and I have 2 questions regarding this code:
- Basically, I'm trying to getting an object MovieDetail but I can't do it after using subscribe() method. This is my code:

```
public MovieDetail getMovieDetail() {
    Observable<MovieDetail> movieDetail = movieDetailService.observe(); // Call method (1)
    movieDetail.subscribe();

    First question:
    // What I need to return here is an object MovieDetail 
    // movieDetail is an Observable<MovieDetail> 
    // So I'd need something like: movieDetail.someMethod() to return an object MovieDetail, but not sure which one I must use

    Second question: 
    // Is it correct to call movieDetail.subscribe(); here or it should be called inside Method (1), something like this:
       movieDetailServiceClientRetrofit
            .getMovieDetails("550")
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .map(movie -> movie.getDetails()) // Return MovieDetail
            .toObservable()
            .subscribe();
}    


// Method (1)
public Observable<MovieDetail> observe() {

    return movieDetailServiceClientRetrofit
            .getMovieDetails("550")
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .map(movie -> movie.getDetails()) // Return MovieDetail
            .toObservable()      // Return Observable<MovieDetail>
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `toObservable()` call at the end because the observer chain is still of type `Observable<>`.

Comment: Actually, it returns a Single that's the reason to use toObservable. 
    @GET("movie/{movie_id}")
        Single<MovieDetail> getMovieDetails(@Path("movie_id") String movieId);

Comment: Leave it as a Single (which is a special type that represents a stream with exactly one element). By converting to Observable you lose useful information.

Answer (score 0):

You may be struggling with the concept of timing, as in "when is the movie detail available?" An `Observable<MovieDetail>` is kind of a promise that eventually a `MovieDetail` object may be emitted.

If you need the object synchronously, you will have to wait for the object to be emitted. There are several ways to do that, including using the `first()` operator variants. These operators will block, waiting for the object to be emitted, and then return the value emitted.

Forcing a step to become synchronous can cost you, but you may be willing to pay the price. Synchronous data handling is much less *reactive*.

Comment: I need to do it async. Probably you think that I want a synchronous call because there is something wrong in my code

Comment: Not so much wrong with your code. You don't say what you want to do with the `MovieDetail` when you get it. Normally, you would handle the `MovieDetail` object in your `subscribe()` step. However, there are a number of ways you could process the object when you received it.

Comment: I just wanted to make it simple. Actually, getMoviesDeatil() is an endpoint which must return a json. @GetMapping(value = "/movie/details", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<MovieDetail> getMovieDetail() {

Comment: Then method 1 would be the way to go. As you originally wrote it.

Comment: Ok, but after these 2 lines, how can I return the model MovieDetail from Observable<MovieDetail> movieDetail. 
Observable<MovieDetail> movieDetail = movieDetailService.observe(); // Call method (1)
    movieDetail.subscribe();

I should do something like this:
movieDetail.someMethod() to return an object MovieDetail, but not sure which one I must use

Comment: Well, returning a `MovieDetail` object means that, at some point, some code must "wait" for the result.